# How can i run my java application as a window service?

Tags: java, exe, executable-jar, winrun4j

I had made a simple java program of screen capture  I want to run that program as a window service but I had trouble im not able to find the right way I had used WinRun4J but at the time of starting the service, I got an error that error 1053 the service didn't respond to start and control service. plz, help with a simple third party which is not complicated to start with im doing this first time?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it with a batch file (`.bat`) and have that batch file as a service.
Gradle eill do it out of the box for you using `distribution` plug-in.

Comment: but how can i stop. bat file because it's a screen capture application

Comment: it will capture screen in every 10sec

Comment: I't not sure what so you mean by screen capture: Autmoatically Periodically? By some key stroke? The Windows service only runs the program. It is your responsibility to design the code to work as you want.

Comment: screen capture means complete ScreenCapure automatically in every 10 sec

Comment: Note that this kind of process will consume a lot of memory and storgae.
You can either stop the service manually, or listen to a keystroke.
However, looks like that you are asking for a lot of functionality that is Windows specific. Thus, it seems that it is better for you to work with C# which contains better API for this kind of tasks.

Comment: why would I change the language as im working in java only

Comment: You shouldn't "work in XXX only". You need to use the most suitable solution to your problem. If your problem is creating an application that extremely uses Windows API, then a programming environment that easily exposes this API is the correct solution.

Comment: that is only my question which API or third party service